# Javascript Object Calling other Object crushing Iterator

Tags: javascript

Okay, so this is complicated so try to bear with me, i will try to keep it as simple as possible:

I have a "class" Struct, that creates a "struct like" skeleton to apply to ArrayBuffers within Javascript. The problem is when I am attempting to mimic the 'c' like behavior of allowing a struct to contain other structs.

The problem is that it clobbers the iterator of the calling method (obviously a closure problem), that i cant seem to figure out.

Here is an example of the code that gets clobbered (hopefully this is enough code to get the answer, if not I will add more as necessary, just trying to keep extraneous code out of here):

```
function StructObject(){
this.applyBuf = function(buf, start){
   var struct = {};
   for (obj in this){
       //problem is here:
       console.log(obj); //prints "c" on the way in
       struct[obj] = this[obj].__createFromBuf();
       console.log(obj); //prints "foo" (see the structs below)
   }
   return struct;
 }
}


function struct(strctObj, name){
var structObject = new StructObject();
...
//create the skeleton
for (item in strctObj){
//the specific code that fails me
structObject[item].__createFromBuf = function(buf, pos){
            return structs[this.name].applyBuf(buf, pos);
}
...
//store the skeleton for later application
structs[name] = structObject;
}


//Creating structs looks like this:
new struct({ foo: type.INT }, "bar");
new struct({
   a: type.INT, //defines size of memory (like c's sizeof)
   b: type.LONG,
   c: {type: type.STRUCT, name: "bar"},
   d: type.SHORT}, "myStruct");

structs.myStruct.applyBuf(new ArrayBuffer(35));
```

When I iterate through the first struct on the class method applyBuf, it calls __createFromBuf on each item within the struct skeleton, if the item is another struct __createFromBuf calls applyBuf on the other "struct skeleton" object and returns an instance of that struct back to the calling struct, which works as intended.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K5DLF/7/) -- Here is the link to a working example :)

Comment: what error does the console say?

Comment: There error is that obj in the loop within StructObject becomes a field from the other object, for example, in the code above before __createFromBuf is called, obj == "c" but after  its called obj== "foo" which is a field from the other object. After that any references based off of this[obj] is undefined, I can fix it with a lame hack but I would rather figure out how to do the right type of closure (the hack is to save the value of the field off before the call and replace it after the return)

Comment: can you provide a simple functional demo that can replicate the error? maybe in a fiddle?

Comment: Definitely, not a problem, will be back with it

Comment: note: clean your `for` statements - if not assigned, the index becomes a `window` or a global member. e.g. `for (item in strctObj)` ==> `for (var item in strctObj)`.

Comment: another thing, be very careful with the use of `this`. remember - **`this` always refer to the function owner**.

Comment: sweet you are awesome @eliran,  put it in an answer and i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean your `for` statements:

if not declared properly, the `for` loop index becomes a global member.

**demonstration:**

```
for (item in strctObj) // item becomes a global member

for (var item in strctObj) // item is scoped within the loop's owner function
```

Comment: Again, thanks for that, javascript is not my strong area, but I've been working it way too much lately, I banged my head on it all day, i thought it was a closure issue.

Comment: sure, thanks for the recognition. also note the comment i made earlier - beware of the `this` keyword, its equivalent in other languages (like C or Java) does not behave in the same manner. you can read further in the [great quirksmode article on the subject](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

Comment: thanks, yeah, I make that mistake often enough, but its usually not too bad, console.log(this) is my best friend (LOL until i have some sort of self referencing object lmao)

Comment: Little nitpicking here regarding *// cool! item is scoped in the loop* This is not 100% true. `item` will be scoped to the function the loop is in as JS has only function scope (no block scope).

Comment: that is accurate, i've updated my answer accordingly, thanks.